# Dependency Injection Operation on the class whose Constructor is fixed

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

In a chatbot project, I keep the users' activities for the last 10 minutes in a session class and send a closing message to the user who has been passive for 10 minutes.

I need to keep all users' information on a single object, so I added the SessionService structure to my services as a Singleton DI.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISessionService, SessionService>();
```

In another part of the project, according to the message sent by the users, a referral is made to a dialogue. Each of these dialogues is composed in the form of a class. These classes are triggered using reflection, so the constructor must be in a fixed structure within the class.

An example of a dialog class

```
public class EndSession : BaseDialog, IAppDialog
{
   public EndSession(Contact contact, Activity activity, Conversation conversation) : 
     base(contact, activity, conversation)
    {
    }
   public void RunDialog()
    {
//Some message sending here
    }
}
```

The project works integrated with dialogflow, detects the closing sentences written by the user (Goodbye, close, thank you) and triggers the RunDialog() method in the EndSession Class.

What I want to do is that while this dialog is triggered, I want to access the SessionService and close the Session belonging to the relevant user.
But because the construction is fixed, I can't make changes to the constructor, so I can't inject a SessionService into the EndSession class.

**I have tried as a solution**

By creating a ServiceProviderFactor, program.when cs was triggered, I created an IServiceProvider from IServiceCollection and added it to the cache. Then I pulled the IServiceProvider from the cache in EndSession and tried to pull the ISESSIONSERVICE from this provider. But from the structure coming from inside the cache, I got a null return when I tried to pull ISessionService.

```
 public static class ServiceProviderFactory
  {
      private static IServiceProvider _serviceProvider { get; set; }
      private static readonly object _lock = new object();
      public static IServiceCollection SetServiceProvider(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
      {
          _serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();          
          CacheManager.Add("servicecollection", _serviceProvider);
          return serviceCollection;
      }

      public static IServiceProvider GetServiceProvider()
      {
          if (_serviceProvider == null)
          {
              lock (_lock)
              {
                  _serviceProvider ??= CacheManager.Get<IServiceProvider>("servicecollection");
              }
          }
          if (_serviceProvider == null)
          {
              throw new InvalidOperationException("IServiceProvider not set. Make sure to set it before using.");
          }
          return _serviceProvider;
      }
  }
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.SetServiceProvider();
```

EndSession.cs

```
var provider = ServiceProviderFactory.GetServiceProvider();
var service = provider.GetService(typeof(ISessionService));
```

How can I inject the SessionService into EndSession without using the constructor?

Comment: HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ISessionService>();
Hope this is what u r looking for??

Comment: I couldn't make the connection you said because HttpContext is an Abstract class and it doesn't have the GetRequiredService method in it. Similar to what you said, I can do this operation via IServiceProvider. After receiving the provider, as I showed above 
`_serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISessionService>();`

i'm doing this operation and I get the following error.

System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'CXPerium.POMadeniYag.Business.ISessionService' has been registered.'

I don't get any errors when I do the same operation when ServiceProvider is first created.

Comment: refer this link u can access DI container instances many ways. pls [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40611683/accessing-asp-net-core-di-container-from-static-factory-class][1]

Comment: _"These classes are triggered using reflection"_ - Why? Is there really no other way? Initialization via reflection should be the last resort approach, e.g. when you know the type of object only during runtime. If you can't change constructors of your services, how else are you planning to use DI?

Comment: _"I created an IServiceProvider from IServiceCollection and added it to the cache"_ - This is a major code smell. In fact, if you manually build service provider in Program.cs, you'll get a warning, please read the message. Current .NET DI is a mechanism created with thought to avoid such centralized, publicly accessible service provider or putting too much stuff in static. Create objects when you need them, keep the amount of singletons to bare minimum. See this question with similar problem and how this can be tackled with proper usage of DI:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40901212/8065832

Comment: This is a chatbot application, if the user's typed sentence is captured within certain regexes, objects are generated in the corresponding type of these regexes and the corresponding method is triggered. The project structure goes through a predefined template, so reflection is used and it is outside my authority to change it. How else can we use a structure instead of Reflection, I can gladly pass on your recommendations to interested friends.

Comment: My chatbot-related classes must have the constructor fixed because they are triggered by reflection.I also have a timer class that I designed with DI as a singleton. When the corresponding chatbot classes are triggered, I need to stop my timer class, so I need to access the timer from within my chatbot classes. As a result, I need to contact DI without taking any action on the constructor. That's why I tried to use the ServiceProvider class.